# Logicapp standard workflows deployment with ARM template

Tags: workflow, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

So I do have a standard logic-app ARM template and I can run and deploy it successfully. Also, I do have some Workflows to be deployed alongside that Standard logic-app. Problem is - the logic-app deploys empty (With no workflows in it).

How do I attach my workflow JSON files to the arm template, so that when deploying, the workflows are included?
Some ARM-template code snippets or pictures would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can add workflow definition in resources section.

- Follow this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-resource-manager-templates-overview) for more details.
- Below is sample template code you can refer and upload json code of your workflow.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
   "parameters": {
      "LogicAppName": {
         "type": "string",
         "minLength": 1,
         "maxLength": 80,
         "defaultValue": "MyLogicApp",
         "metadata": {
            "description": "The resource name to use for the logic app"
         }
      },
      "LogicAppLocation": {
         "type": "string",
         "minLength": 1,
         "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
         "metadata": {
            "description": "The resource location to use for the logic app"
         }
      },
      "office365_1_Connection_Name": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "office365",
         "metadata": {
            "description": "The resource name to use for the Office 365 Outlook connection"
         }
      },
      "office365_1_Connection_DisplayName": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "",
         "metadata": {
            "description": "The display name to use for the Office 365 Outlook connection"
         }
      },
      "azureblob_1_Connection_Name": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "azureblob",
         "metadata": {
            "description": "The resource name to use for the Azure Blob storage account connection"
         }
      },
      "azureblob_1_Connection_DisplayName": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "",
         "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the storage account the connector should use."
         }

      },
      "azureblob_1_accountName": {
         "type": "string",
         "defaultValue": "",
         "metadata": {
            "description": "Name of the storage account the connector should use."
         }
      },
      "azureblob_1_accessKey": {
         "type": "securestring",
         "metadata": {
            "description": "Specify a valid primary/secondary storage account access key."
         }
      },
      "LogicAppIntegrationAccount": {
         "type":"string",
         "minLength": 1,
         "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/<Azure-subscription-ID>/resourceGroups/fabrikam-integration-account-rg/providers/Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/fabrikam-integration-account",
         "metadata": {
            "description": "The ID to use for the integration account"
         }
      }
   },
   "variables": {},
   "resources": [
      {
         "properties": {
            "state": "Disabled",
            "integrationAccount": {
              "id": "[parameters('LogicAppIntegrationAccount')]"
            },
            "definition": {
               "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
               "actions": {
                  "Create_blob": {
                     "type": "ApiConnection",
                     "inputs": {
                        "host": {
                           "connection": {
                              "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "method": "post",
                     "body": "@triggerBody()?['Body']",
                     "path": "/datasets/default/files",
                     "queries": {
                        "folderPath": "/emails",
                        "name": "@triggerBody()?['Subject']",
                        "queryParametersSingleEncoded": true
                     },
                     "runAfter": {},
                     "runtimeConfiguration": {
                        "contentTransfer": {
                           "transferMode": "Chunked"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "parameters": {
                  "$connections": {
                     "defaultValue": {},
                     "type": "Object"
                  }
               },
               "triggers": {
                  "When_a_new_email_arrives": {
                     "type": "ApiConnection",
                     "inputs": {
                        "host": {
                           "connection": {
                              "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                           }
                        },
                        "method": "get",
                        "path": "/Mail/OnNewEmail",
                        "queries": {
                           "folderPath": "Inbox",
                           "importance": "Any",
                           "fetchOnlyWithAttachment": false,
                           "includeAttachments": false
                        }
                     },
                     "recurrence": {
                        "frequency": "Day",
                        "interval": 1
                     },
                     "splitOn": "@triggerBody()?['value']"
                  }
               },
               "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
               "outputs": {}
            },
            "parameters": {
               "$connections": {
                  "value": {
                     "azureblob": {
                        "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('LogicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'azureblob')]",
                        "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('azureblob_1_Connection_Name'))]",
                        "connectionName": "[parameters('azureblob_1_Connection_Name')]"
                     },
                     "office365": {
                        "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('LogicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'office365')]",
                        "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('office365_1_Connection_Name'))]",
                        "connectionName": "[parameters('office365_1_Connection_Name')]"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "accessControl": {}
         },
         "name": "[parameters('LogicAppName')]",
         "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
         "location": "[parameters('LogicAppLocation')]",
         "tags": {
            "displayName": "LogicApp"
         },
         "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
         "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('azureblob_1_Connection_Name'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', parameters('office365_1_Connection_Name'))]"
         ]
      },
      {
         "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
         "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
         "name": "[parameters('office365_1_Connection_Name')]",
         "location": "[parameters('LogicAppLocation')]",
         "properties": {
            "api": {
                "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('LogicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'office365')]"
            },
            "displayName": "[parameters('office365_1_Connection_DisplayName')]"
         }
      },
      {
         "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
         "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
         "name": "[parameters('azureblob_1_Connection_Name')]",
         "location": "[parameters('LogicAppLocation')]",
         "properties": {
            "api": {
               "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('LogicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'azureblob')]"
            },
            "displayName": "[parameters('azureblob_1_Connection_DisplayName')]",
            "parameterValues": {
               "accountName": "[parameters('azureblob_1_accountName')]",
               "accessKey": "[parameters('azureblob_1_accessKey')]"
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "outputs": {}
}
```

- Workflow definition need to be included in Microsoft.Logic/workflows`resource type.
- Using custom deployment in azure portal, I have uploaded above template file and it is created logic app, blob api connection and office 365 connection.
  [image]

Comment: Much appreciated, but this throws an error for me while trying to deploy the custom template: "The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'method' on object of type 'FlowTemplateAction'. Path 'properties.definition.actions.Create_blob.method'"

Comment: Also, I checked the documentation You linked. That documentation refers to only the multi-tenant (Consumption) version of Logic-app which uses ARM templates and has tutorials on how to do it. My case is different, I am trying to deploy a single-tenant (Standard) version of Logic-app which has multiple workflows in it. And I am trying to understand how do I add those workflows to the deployment. Even the GitHub repowith demo project do not address this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to accomplish the same thing and cannot find any resources online referencing this. I found the differentiating factor between what we want to deploy in my case is multiple workflows in the "Logic App Standard" which is technically an App Service behind the scenes - requiring an app service plan and storage account to deploy:

- "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
- "kind": "functionapp,workflowapp"

While all resources and Microsoft templates / examples refer to "Logic App" which is:

- "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows"

I can define the workflow definitions in the resources property of the logic app standard arm template but it only deploys the logic app, and no workflows (even if they are defined) just like you outlined above.

Comment: Use MSDeploy extension for Microsoft.Web for creating Standard LogicApp workflows after deploying your Microsoft.Web/sites LogicApp (Which is created without any workflows).

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2021-03-01/sites/extensions-msdeploy?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template

You can use PackageUri option and pass path of ZIP file which contains the Workflow folders and  parameters.json, connections.json, host,json file at the root.

`LogicZip
- Workflow1
    -- workflow.json
- Workflow2
    -- workflow.json
- parameter.json`

Answer (score 0):

Standard LogicApps are deployed on AppServicePlan, when you create a serverfarm(App Service Plan) and then deploy your Microsoft.Web/sites(LogicApp) on top of it, workflows, parameters and connections will not be deployed by default.

You will have to use `MSDeploy` extension for Microsoft.Web for deploying Standard LogicApp workflows after deploying your Microsoft.Web/sites.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2021-03-01/sites/extensions-msdeploy?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template

You can use PackageUri option and pass the local path of ZIP file (Or Azure Blob Storage Link) which contains the Workflow folders and parameters.json, connections.json, host.json file at the root. The structure inside the Zip file should look like below (Names enclosed in {{}} are customizable):

```
- {{WorkflowName1}}  
  -- workflow.json 
- {{WorkflowName2}}    
  -- workflow.json 
- parameter.json
- connections.json
- host.json
```

Also, if you are trying to deploy the Zip from Local Path, you will have to add ParameterReference in ARM deploymentParameter template.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "paths": [
    {
      "ParameterReference": "local_zip_path"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "local_zip_path": {
      "value": "bin\\LogicApps.zip"
    }
  }
}
```